# Overcoming the issue of Lazy Initialization and Performance using Hibernate in Struts 2

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, struts2, lazy-initialization

In Hibernate, `@ManyToOne` relationship hardly results any problem since default fetch type is `EAGER`.

However, we encounter critical problems at the `@OnetoMany` end. As we attempt to fetch a collection,

```
LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
```

is thrown since the default fetch type is `LAZY` for *one-to-many*.

In such case, we shall either set:

- `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)`, which although it resolves the problem, it hits the performance significantly when there are bunch of records.
- `fetch` mode: left join but it throws

  ```
  org.hibernate.HibernateException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
  ```

According to my knowledge, Hibernate suggests couple of mechanisms to overcome this issue:

- **Option 1:**

  - Specifying `@IndexColumn` instead of making `LazyCollectionOption.FALSE`. As a consequnce, the following behaviors are identified which also impacts on the performance:
  - A temporary table is created with primary keys of respective entities (`@OnetoMany`). So when there are many *one-to-many* relationships, temporary table is created for each.
- **Option 2:**

  - Changing data type of collection from `List` to `Set`. This is leads to a problematic situation at the front-end with Struts 2 because `Set` is index based collection as we need to add records dynamically in an iterative manner.
  - In order to overcome this issue, we shall make use of DTOs to capture UI inputs. By making collection type `List` in DTO and `Set` in *domain*, and by having assembler we shall do the required conversion from `List` → `Set` (DTO → Domain), and vice versa.

Is the resolution mentioned under Option 2 a viable solution? If not, please provide suggestions and feedback.

Comment: Never fetch that lazy collections unless you know what are you doing.

Comment: if I change to EAGER it will have severe impact on performance

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you usually have only one or two places where you need eager initialization (example: in a "record details" view). For such situations, where lazy will be always the case, except for a couple of places where eager is needed, there's a Hibernate feature called ["Fetch profile"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles). It's a relatively new feature, not very known, but it's very powerful and can probably help in this case.

Unfortunately, this is not in JPA yet, which means that you'll need to add a bit of proprietary Hibernate parts in your otherwise clean JPA code, but it's a low price to pay, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The `LazyInitializationException` is thrown if you are trying to access objects in *one-to-many* properties or collections and doesn't have an open session at the moment.

The association is designed by default for *lazy initialization* and this is good approach for performance issue to have *one-to-many* properties that could be initialized on demand.

The only problem is with the session state. For this purpose Hibernate has imposed [Open Session In View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern.

You could implement it manually using a custom interceptor or use already implemented via [Full Hibernate Plugin for Struts2](https://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/).

See how this plugin could be used with Struts2 jQuery Grid plugin in their [showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase).