# org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: java, json, hibernate, struts2, lazy-initialization

I am calling autocomplete from JSP  `url: "ProductByName"`.
On response in console it is showing

```
POST http://localhost:8082/Store/SingleProduct 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**In JSP:**

```
 $(".name").autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "ProductByName",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                str: request.term,
                                maxRows: 5
                            },...
```

**In `struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="ProductByName" class="iland.productdetails.ProductDetailsAction" method="fetchByProductName">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="includeProperties">productList\[\d+\]\.id,
                    productList\[\d+\]\.name,
                    productList\[\d+\]\.description
                </param>
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

I want to fetch only few properties of `productList`

**In Action class:**

```
public class ProductDetailsAction extends ActionSupport {

private long id;

private String barCode;//bardoce

private String name;
private String desc;

private long quantity;
private float unitPrice;
private float sellingPrice;
private float totalSellingPrice;
private long clientId;
private ArrayList<BillDetails> BillList;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private int discountPercentage;
private Timestamp addDate;
private String dataStatus;
private ArrayList<ProductDetailsAction> productList;
private ArrayList<Product> productBillList;
public String fetchByProductName() {
         ProductDetailsBusiness pdb = new ProductDetailsBusiness();
          Map data = pdb.fetchByProductName(getName());
          setProductList((ArrayList) data.get("list"));
          return SUCCESS;
  }
   //other methods and getter and setter
    }
```

**I am getting following exception:**

```
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: iland.hbm.Client.billDetailses, no session or session was closed
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: iland.hbm.Client.billDetailses, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:102)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: iland.hbm.Client.billDetailses, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: iland.hbm.Client.billDetailses, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: iland.hbm.Client.billDetailses, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.equals(PersistentSet.java:429)
    at java.util.Vector.indexOf(Vector.java:408)
    at java.util.Vector.contains(Vector.java:367)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:117)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 81 more
```

**Edit:**

`fetchByProductName(getName());` method contains only Jdbc code. Then why Hibernate Errorrs??

I am fetching date from database and also printing on console. before success I gave `System.out.println(`In action`);` this is aslo printing properly
It doesnt have to access data from database then why  `failed to lazily initialize a collection of XXX`
How to resolve this.

**Edit:**

```
 public class ProductDetailsBusiness {

ProductDetailsAction pda = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null, res = null;
Connection con = null;
String status = null;
ArrayList<ProductDetailsAction> ar = null;

public Map fetchByProductName(String name, long cid) {
        System.out.println(" ProductBusiness fetchByProductName()");
        status = "success";
        System.out.println("Name is " + name);

        ar = new ArrayList();
        con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

        try {
            String query = "select * from product "
                    + "where status=? and cid=? "
                    + "order by add_date";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, "active");
             ps.setLong(2, cid);
            System.out.println("Before execution");
            res = ps.executeQuery();

            System.out.println("Details are");
            while (res.next()) {
                pda = new ProductDetailsAction();
                long id1 = res.getLong("id");
                String barCode = res.getString("barcode");
                String name1 = res.getString("name");
                String desc = res.getString("description");
                long quntity = res.getLong("quntity");
                float unit_price = res.getLong("unit_price");
                float selling_price = res.getLong("selling_price");
                int discount_percent = res.getInt("discount_percent");
                pda.setId(id1);
                pda.setBarCode(barCode);
                pda.setName(name1);
                pda.setDesc(desc);
                pda.setQuantity(quntity);
                pda.setUnitPrice(unit_price);
                pda.setSellingPrice(selling_price);
                pda.setDiscountPercentage(discount_percent);
                System.out.println("id "+id1+" name "+name1+" "+desc);
                ar.add(pda);
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            status = "failure";
            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute." + s);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqe) {
                status = "failure";
                System.out.println("SQLException " + sqe);
            }
        }
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("status", status);
        m.put("list", ar);
        return m;
    }
      //other methods
    }
```

Also updated action class Please also see it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21099135/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios I would Like to fetch only few properties. on setting `FetchType.EAGER` with collection it is  showing `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20565206/573032

Comment: I tried to your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23989812/876739 IS `includeProperties` and `excludeNullProperties` is correct

Comment: fetchByProductName(getName());` method contains only Jdbc code. But why it is shoing Hibernate exception.

Comment: @xrcwrn If you are using hibernate to map your entity classes then each instance you get from the hibernate session returns references managed by hibernate even if they are in the detached state.

Comment: @RomanC  On `fetchByProductName()` before success I added `sout("returning from action);` So this line is also printing without any `Exception`. After this exceptions are thrown. I think problem in `struts.xml` could you tell me is ther any problem/correction above struts.xml

Comment: @xrcwrn: What exactly you are asking? Hibernate exception is probably due to use of hibernate annotations on your entity. Lazy init exception is being thrown because you haven't init all properties on fetch. So what do you not understand?

Comment: @xrcwrn post code for `ProductDetailsBusiness` & beans in method `fetchByProductName`

Comment: @xrcwrn Lazy initialization is replaced by IoC, this is an old paradigm for object instantiation, is managed by Hibernate, that's why it requires an open session. Could you provide a code for action class?

Comment: @Yogi I have updated my Action class and Added `fetchByProductName()` method.

Comment: @xrcwrn first of all I did not see it clearly in the start but this issue is related to your `SingleProduct` action not `ProductByName` so would suggest provide code related to this, and make sure you tried using `Hibernate.initialize(data)` in `SingleProduct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialization process to JSON is controlled by JSON result, which is a part of the [JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html) that you used in your project. And you already know that to limit properties used by serializer you should use `includeProperties` of the `json` result. There's also `root` property that you should examine. If not specified the json result uses by default the `top` object of the value stack. If your action is model driven then *model overrides action*. So, the regexes you used in the `includeProperties` apply to the model object, and serializer which is `JSONWriter` uses `BeanInfo` to extract properties of the bean. First, these properties are checked for existence of `@JSON` annotation and if it has `serialize=false`, then it's skipped, otherwise it's included. This way you can control the serialization process via putting annotations on the properties that you won't serialize to JSON such as `@OneToMany` properties, etc. Then `includeProperties` or `excludeProperties` are checked if they are not empty. At this time you should acknowledge that if you don't have properties that matches to the patterns specified then them won't be serialized. So, lets move to `LazyInitializationException`, as I said if you have `@JSON` annotation ever in the model hierarchy you should put `serialize=false` inside it because by default it's `true`.

```java
@JSON(serialize=false)
public Object getBillDetailses(){ return billDetailses; }
```

You said your `productList` in the action class, then you should configure the result

```xml
<!-- Result config -->
<result type="json">
  <param name="includeProperties">
    ^productList\[\d+\]\.id,
    ^productList\[\d+\]\.name,
    ^productList\[\d+\]\.description
  </param>
  <param name="root">
    #action
  </param>
</result>
```

Note, that `^` stands for beginning the expression, so only action properties will be  included.

Answer (score 1):

[`LazyInitializationException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html) is root cause in this problem which is thrown when Struts 2 json plugin tries to serialize your `productList` object. as per the exception document

> (It) Indicates access to unfetched data outside of a session context. 
>   For example, when an uninitialized proxy or collection is accessed
>   after the session was closed.

this means you are trying to access collection of `billDetailses` entity which was loaded in form of hibernate proxy in java from database. As per hibernate **[document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization)**

> A LazyInitializationException will be thrown by Hibernate if an uninitialized collection or proxy is accessed outside of the scope of the Session, i.e., when the entity owning the collection or having the reference to the proxy is in the detached state.

so this means `list` collections of `billDetailses` is not initialized which you can force initialize before completing action
using

```
Hibernate.initialize(data) // collection entity
```

Setting `FetchType.EAGER` on collection mapping also solves the problem but it will add over head to `billDetailses` object as every time this object is loaded in java it's collection will be force loaded and from my consideration it is like buying Ferrari and always running it in 1st gear.

If you get `LazyInitializationException` very often I suggest try using [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) which keeps your hibernate session open from start of request until the response is completed from your application.

Comment: 'fetchByProductName(getName());` method contains only Jdbc code. Then why Hibernate Errorrs??

Comment: I don't understand are you using Hibernate as datasource or JDBC? cause from the exception that you put in example suggest that you are using hibernate `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`

Comment: In My project. In some part I am using jdbc and in some I am using Hiberate. For this code I am getting values from jdbc from database

Comment: I am sure that some where some how this object is associated with Hibernate session else how would there be `LazyInitializationException ` exception?

Comment: On fetchByProductName() before success I added sout("returning from action); So this line is also printing without any Exception. After this exceptions are thrown. I think problem in struts.xml could you tell me is ther any problem/correction above struts.xml

Comment: What's the equivalent of `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in Struts 2?