# Ajax call always going to error function in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

I am trying to return json from action by ajax call in struts 2 but it's always taking me to the `error` function.
Here i am trying to take the `cartsize` by ajax call and want to print the cartsize whenever someone click on add to cart but it's taking me to `error function` always

**Here is my ajax call**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function addProductToCart(productId)
            {
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'addProductToCart',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {productId: productId},
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("In success");
                         $('#result').html(data.cartSize);
                         alert(data.cartSize);

                        
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                        console.log('Error occured!!');
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });

                }
                </script>
```

**My Action Class only the addProduct method**

```
public String addProductToCart(){
        System.out.println("Cart: " + productId);
        MenuServices item = new MenuServices();
        if (sessionMap.get("Cart") == null) {
            HashMap<Integer, Menu> cart = new HashMap<>();

            try {
                Menu product = item.fetchProduct(productId);
                cart.put(productId, product);
                getSessionMap().put("Cart", cart);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReservationAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } else {
            HashMap cart = (HashMap) sessionMap.get("Cart");
            try {
                Menu product = item.fetchProduct(productId);
                cart.put(productId, product);
                getSessionMap().put("Cart", cart);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReservationAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        HashMap cart = (HashMap) sessionMap.get("Cart");
        setCartSize(cart.size());
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<package name="base" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <action name="addProductToCart" class="com.tablebooking.actions.ReservationAction" method = "addProductToCart">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="root">action</param>
    </result>
</action>
    </package>
```

Comment: Hard to diagnose without knowing the error message.

Comment: no error it's showing it's taking me to the error function of my ajax

Comment: If the error callback runs, then there must have been an error.
The `error` callback receives three arguments; `(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown)`.
The error message is represented by `textStatus` and/or `errorThrown`.
Log them both to discover the error message.

Comment: Show your action class fully. Probably you have a problem with json result serialization. The plugin might supress errors during the process but you need to control the json structure returned to the client. In the previous answer I suggested to use `root` parameter for the result to the action, because you needed a property to return. Now you have some properties that might break the serialization process and should be excluded. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24445373/573032) is a similar problem.

Comment: @RomanC i have added the whole action class, Please check I have also tried by creating a new action class with a single method where i created variable and tried to return that but still that was taking me to the error thing, I don't understand why it is not working

Comment: The error message is still unknown. The action class should extend `ActionSupport` to get errors.

Comment: @RomanC how will i get to know what is the error actually

Comment: Errors are written to the server log, you can also call `hasErrors()`.

Comment: @RomanC this is what i see in the serverlog -- SEVERE [http-nio-9494-exec-39] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/OnlineTableBooking] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

Comment: @RomanC i have just included  commons-lang3-3.1.jar and now it's working, Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I thought the problem in serialization to json. You can change the value of the param to `noData` to return only this property or put this property to another object which you can use for Json and configure it to the result.